# Difference between name and referencedColumnName in @JoinColumn annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "someValue" , referencedColumnName = "someOtherValue" )
```

What values are to be placed in `name` and `referencedColumnName` column if 2 tables are linked by `ManyToOne` association?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Suppose you have Two tables:

```
1. Department table with columns:
 a. Dept_ID (primary key)
 b. Dept_Name

2. Employee Table with following column:
  a. Emp_Id (primary key)
  b. Dept_Id_fk (foreign key)
  c. Salary
```

Now your join column for Employee Entity class will be

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "Dept_Id_fk", referencedColumnName = "Dept_ID")
Department department;
```

So referencedColumnName means column that you are referencing to from your foreign key column.

Comment: You are welcome! 
If that answered your query, don't forgot to mark it as answer! Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please provide a working example of how to map with JPA/Hibernate a @ManytoMany relationship between two tables each having composite primary keys ?

Answer (score 0):

How would the join column look like for oneToMany association? Here is an example:

Person table:

person_id (pk), person_name

person_reltn table:

person_reltn_id (pk),
child_person_id (fk),
parent_person_id (fk)

For the above tables, if I were to create the Person entity:

```
 class Person(){
    
     @Id
      @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
      private long personId;
    
      @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
      @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(
          name = "CHILD_PERSON_ID",
          referencedColumnName = "PERSON_ID",
          updatable = false,
          insertable = false)
      @Where(clause = "ACTIVE_IND = 1")
      @Filter(
          name = FilterConstants.END_EFFECTIVE_DATE_TIME_FILTER,
          condition = FilterConstants.END_EFFECTIVE_DATE_TIME_CONDITION)
      @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
      private final List<PersonRelation> personRelations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In the joinColumn, should the name always have the foreign key (which means the value from  entity you are joining to) and the referenceColumnName should alway have the primary key on the entity? If yes, it will be the opposite of Sayantan's response above. Please let me know if I misunderstood the concept.

Update on 03/04/2021

After doing more research, I found the documentation on how to set the referenceColumnName based on the entity mappings[1]. Looks like, for unidirectional OneToMany mapping, the referenced column is in the table of the source entity.

1.https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html