# Jpa is getting inconsistent data, from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am using Jpa in order to communicate with database, but the data I am taking in inconsistent. I have a user class that has a OneToOne relationship with a Teacher class.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
private Teacher teacher; // From user class

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private User user;  // from the teacher class
```

I am saving a teacher in the following way:

```
public Teacher save(Teacher teacher, Long id)
{
    User user;
    Optional<User> ifUser = userRepo.findById(id);
    if(ifUser.isPresent()) {
        user= ifUser.get();
        user.setTeacher(teacher);
        user.setCompletedInfo(1);
        teacher.setUser(user);
        return teacherRepo.save(teacher);
    }else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find any user here...");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Where userRepo and teacherRepo are interfaces that extend from JpaRepository. Until now it works pretty cool. The information gets updated in the database. But when I get the info from the database, it shows me that

```
 user.getCompletedInfo()
```

is null. Meanwhile I can see in the database that that value:

```
user.getCompletedInfo() =1;
```

The database is MySql, and a possible approach to the problem I would think is that I am getting some info from a new User Object that is being created somewhere.
For more the project is in Github: https://github.com/shpendpalushi/JavaWeb/tree/For_Project

Edit:
From some Unit testing I was able to find that in the teacher service setUser wasn't  doing it's job properly. When I tried to getUser it returned me a null;
Am I doing something wrong in the save method?

Comment: `But when I get the info from the database, it shows me that` how do you get it from database? I think when it is saved teacher, right? then that method save return teacher and it gets user then get that field, right?

Comment: Sorry it was misleading, yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code on github i believe you have mixed up your references

```
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private User user;
```

`name` is pointing out what column in the current entity should be used.

`referencedColumnName` is pointing out what FK it should be pointing at.

so if you switch it

```
@JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
```

You are instead saying, the column id in the entity teacher, should point at the column user_id in user.

But thats my quick guess.

[name vs referencedColumnName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287631/difference-between-name-and-referencedcolumnname-in-joincolumn-annotation)

Comment: From what I saw from [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column), it used to do in my way, anyways it tried changing that, and still the same. Still the result comes null and in the database is updated.