# Suitable class to include @JoinColumn annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-annotations

I can't understand the `@JoinColumn` theory, as you see in the picture:

[Screenshot with my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqiOE.png)

Seems the `@JoinColumn` annotation in `@ManytoOne` and `@OneToMany` does not follow the same rule.

Does `@JoinColumn(name="course_id")` should be in the Review class?
How can I know where to include this annotation every time I need it?

Comment: It is possible on both sides.

Comment: There is also `@JoinColumns` that specifies both sides at once.

Comment: This might help you to understand how to use join column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287631/difference-between-name-and-referencedcolumnname-in-joincolumn-annotation/53287912#53287912

Comment: I think this previous answer will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119531/hibernate-jpa-manytoone-vs-onetomany